# reports using HTML and CSS result in imperfect page borders

Tags: html, css, vb.net, report

I'm using the Winforms library nuget Kimtoo.Reports. This library functions to create reports using CSS and HTML. I think this is the problem with css or html code that makes the border result disconnected or imperfect and there is a sequence number missing on page 3. I have no experience in css or html languages. Please recommend

Thanks

```
Private Sub GenerateReport()
KtReport1.Clear()
KtReport1.AddHorizontalRule()
KtReport1.AddDataTable(dtCloned, "width=100% border=2 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0")
End Sub
```

PAGE1

[image: PAGE1]

PAGE2

[image: PAGE2]

PAGE3

[image: PAGE3]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the relevant CSS and HTML. As there are a lot of rows in the table, just 3 or 4 rows should be enough to see what the problem could be.

Comment: @AndrewMorton , I have updated and for the page can not because of a problem on the next page or after the first page